# Call to a member function detail() on bool laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

my product model

```
    public function detail(){

    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\ProductDetails');
}
```

my productDetails model

```
protected $table='product_details';
public $timestamps=false;
protected $fillable=['product_id' , 'show_slider','show_opportunity_day','show_featured','show_bestseller','show_discounted'];

public function detail(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Products');
}
```

my ProductTableSeeder

```
       DB::table('products')->truncate();
    DB::table('product_details')->truncate();
    $products=[
        ["product_name"=>"Domates Çorbası", "slug"=>'Domates Çorbası', 'content'=>"en iyi ürün","price"=>20 ],
        ["product_name"=>"Yayla Çorbası", "slug"=>"Yayla Çorbası", "content"=>"en iyi ürün","price"=>30],
        ["product_name"=>"Kelle Paça Çorbası", "slug"=>"Kelle Paça Çorbası", "content"=>"en iyi ürün","price"=>20],
        ["product_name"=>"Tarhana Çorbası","slug"=>"Tarhana Çorbası", "content"=>"en iyi ürün","price"=>40 ],
        ["product_name"=>"Tavuk Çorbası", "slug"=>"Tavuk Çorbası", "content"=>"en iyi ürün","price"=>10  ],
        ["product_name"=>"Mercimek Çorbası", "slug"=>"Mercimek Çorbası", "content"=>"en iyi ürün","price"=>15 ],
        ["product_name"=>"Kereviz Çorbası", "slug"=>"Kereviz Çorbası", "content"=>"en iyi ürün","price"=>25 ],
        ["product_name"=>"Şehriyeli Çorba", "slug"=>"Şehriyeli Çorba", "content"=>"en iyi ürün","price"=>22 ],
        ["product_name"=>"Havuçlu Kabak Çorbası", "slug"=>"Havuçlu Kabak Çorbası", "content"=>"en iyi ürün","price"=>14],
        ["product_name"=>"Ayran Çorbası", "slug"=>"Ayran Çorbası", "content"=>"en iyi ürün","price"=>20 ]
    ];
    foreach($products as $product){
    DB::table('products')->insert($products);
    $detail=$product->detail()->create([
        'show_slider'=>rand(0,1),
        'show_opportunity_day'=>rand(0,1),
        'show_featured'=>rand(0,1),
        'show_bestseller'=>rand(0,1),
        'show_discounted'=>rand(0,1)
    ]);
    }
```

$ product is not defined in the seeder section and when I save and refresh the page I get an error--->
Call to a member function detail() on bool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the seeder file like this

```
 foreach($products as $product){
    $product=Products::create($product);
    $detail=$product->detail()->create([
        'show_slider'=>rand(0,1),
        'show_opportunity_day'=>rand(0,1),
        'show_featured'=>rand(0,1),
        'show_bestseller'=>rand(0,1),
        'show_discounted'=>rand(0,1)
```